# How do I take a .jpg photo instead of .mov

Tags: iphone, photos

I'm trying to use an Iphone 13 Mini to take pictures of some documents, but when I use the camera app., it keeps creating `.mov` files, when I want a format like `.jpg`.   I tried changing the camera settings from "High Efficiency" to "Compatible" but that has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you viewing this on?
If Windows, it will break a Live Photo into component parts, photo & video, because it cannot keep the 'live' part together with the actual photo. Only Mac can do that.

On the Camera screen, you can switch Live mode on & off with the circular icon, top right [marked in red] but also make sure you are set to either Photo or Portrait mode, bottom centre.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  "Portrait Mode" did the trick!

Comment: Watch out for portrait mode if there isn't a face in the scene, it can refuse to take - because it expects a face to do some 'cool' effects it can apply to the scene. Regular 'photo' is a better bet, with Live switched off.